# Replace form GET submit with a curl GET request

Tags: php, curl, get, instagram

I authenticate an Instagram user with the server-side flow according to the Instagram API documentation. Once a user successfully authenticates and authorizes my application, the API returns a "code" to the redirect_uri, which I then  exchange for an access-token. All this works fine when I initiate the process as follows in my HTML markup. I would like to replace the markup with a curl GET request, which I thought would act the same as the form submit which has method="GET". I receive a response header from the curl request with an http_code=200 however I am not receiving the response packet that I receive when I submit the form. Is there something wrong with my curl request or am I mistaken in thinking that the curl GET request will act the same as the form GET.

```
HTML markup:   
<div id="instagramConnect">
      <form id="instagram-signin" 
            action="<?php echo($i->instagram_arr['authorize_url']) ?>" method="GET">
          <input type="hidden" name="client_id" 
            value="<?php echo($i->instagram_arr['client_id']) ?>" />
          <input type="hidden" name="redirect_uri"
            value="<?php echo ($i->instagram_arr['redirect_uri']) ?>" />
          <input type="hidden" name="response_type" value="code" />
          <input type="submit" id="instagram-submit" value="Signin to Instagram"></input>
        </form>
    </div>


Would like to replace markup with this curl:        
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_URL => 
        $i->instagram_arr["authorize_url"].
        '?client_id='.$i->instagram_arr["client_id"].
        '&redirect_uri='.$i->instagram_arr["redirect_uri"].
        '&response_type=code'
        ));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_errno ( $curl );
    $errmsg = curl_error ( $curl );
    $header = curl_getinfo ( $curl);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo ( $curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );

    print_r($httpCode); //returns 200
    echo $resp; //should be an access code but nothing

    }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Instagram API, but is it possible you need the Header Content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

Comment: Would that apply if I were doing an HTTP POST? My form is working using method=GET so I think I have set up the curl as an HTTP GET.